# ANSI escape code. SGR 10-19. Alternative fonts

Tags: terminal, fonts, ansi-escape

Please help me understand the SGR parameters of ANSI escape code from 10 to 19

```
\033[12m
```

The sources only indicate about them:

| SGR parameter | Name | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11-19 | Alternative font | Select alternative font n − 10 |

I would like to find out and figure out what alternative fonts are and how these ANSI commands work.

Operating system - Windows 11. File .py run in the default Command Line. Python code:

```
print('\033[10m', end='')
print('font0 TEST123test')
print('\033[11m', end='')
print('font1 TEST123test')
print('\033[12m', end='')
print('font2 TEST123test')

print('\033[0;33m', end='')
print('TEST123test')
print('\033[1;33m', end='')
print('TEST123test')
```

Result of code execution: [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glaaV.png)

I believe that fonts should be changed to some alternative ones, but I don't understand what and how this should happen, and what else should I configure.